# notation of all possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics, notation

Suppose we have list of Q integers $p_1, p_2,..., p_Q$.  In round $k$ we have combinations of the integers. For example Q = 3, the combinations of $k$ round are:

k= 1,  $p_1, p_2,p_3$ .

k= 2, $p_1p_1, p_1p_2,p_1p_3$,

$p_1p_2, p_2p_2,p_2 p_3$,

$p_1p_3, p_2p_3, p_3p_3$.

k = 3, $p_1p_1p_1, p_1p_1p_2,p_1p_1p_3$
  $p_1p_2p_1, p_1p_2p_2,p_1p_2 p_3$
 $p_1p_3p_1, p_1p_3p_2,p_1p_3p_3$,...,

$p_3p_3p_1,p_3p_3p_2,p_3p_3p_3$

k=4,  $p_1p_1p_1p_1, p_1p_1p_1p_2,p_1p_1p_1p_3$,

$p_1p_1p_1p_2p_2, p_2p_1p_2p_2,p_1p_1p_2 p_3,$...,

$ p_1p_1p_3p_Q,p_1p_2p_3p_3, ...,p_3p_3p_3p_3$

How do I mathematically formulate this problem using kind of   $\sum \prod$?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I like

$$S(k)=\{p_{\sigma_1}p_{\sigma_2}\cdots p_{\sigma_k}:1\leq\sigma_1\leq\sigma_2\leq\cdots\leq \sigma_k\leq Q\}.$$

Comment: Thanks 

I believe your answer only apply for maximum $k$ is $Q$, In my question, $k$ can be greater than Q. How do I solve it?

Comment: ...think again... there is nothing stopping $k$ being greater than $Q$... it's just that some of the $\sigma_i$ MUST be equal. For example, suppose k=3 and Q=2 then the sigmas are (1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,2,2), (2,2,2) which are all captured by my notation.